# angularjs: disable radio button whilst not actually disabling it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to disable a radio button but still be able to tab through it.  It seems that actually setting it to disabled takes it out of the tab rotation.

I have therefore done the following:

```
<input type="radio" class="appear-disabled" ng-keypress="suppressKeyboard($event)" name="contestedDataYes" ng-model= REDACTED.contestedData ng-value="'Y'" ng-checked="REDACTED.contestedData === 'Y'" aria-label="Yes">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;
<input type="radio" class="appear-disabled" ng-keypress="suppressKeyboard($event)" name="contestedDataNo" ng-model= REDACTED.contestedData ng-value="'N'" ng-checked="REDACTED.contestedData === 'N'" aria-label="No">&nbsp;No&nbsp;

.appear-disabled {
 opacity: .5;
 pointer-events: none;
}

$scope.suppressKeyboard = function(event) {
 var keyCode = event.keyCode;

 // 32 = space, 13 = enter
 if (keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 32) {
   event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
 }
};
```

This makes the radio group appear (visually) to be disabled and prevents mouse clicks on the radio buttons but does not prevent tabbing onto a radio button and hitting space or enter to toggle it.

Why is the suppressKeyboard function not preventing the keyboard inputs?

Comment: why just dont use ng-disabled ?

Comment: because you can't tab onto a disabled element

Comment: you want only work with click ???

Comment: the css disables the mouse click interactions.  I need to disable the keyboard interactions as well.

Comment: Check if with the modifications in the answer satisfy the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change ng-keypress to `ng-keydown` and in the function do this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" class="appear-disabled" ng-keydown="suppressKeyboard($event)" name="contestedDataYes" ng-model= REDACTED.contestedData ng-value="'Y'" ng-checked="REDACTED.contestedData === 'Y'" aria-label="Yes">&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;
<input type="radio" class="appear-disabled" ng-keydown="suppressKeyboard($event)" name="contestedDataNo" ng-model= REDACTED.contestedData ng-value="'N'" ng-checked="REDACTED.contestedData === 'N'" aria-label="No">&nbsp;No&nbsp;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.suppressKeyboard = function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    // 32 = space, 13 = enter

    if (keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 32) {
       //event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = 
       false);
      event.preventDefault();
     }
 };
```

- `keydown` -> can be prevented -> fired when: press a key
- `keypress` -> can be prevented -> fired when: hold a key
- `keyup` -> can not be prevented -> fired when: release a key